# Q：ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python, linux, pip

Please help!!!
I try to execute these two commands：

```
git clone https://github.com/oxwhirl/smac.git
pip install -e smac/
```

But when I execute the last command I get an error

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Obtaining file:///home/jin/smac
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-6ikzqo2m/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-awnh2not/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (8 lines):
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd0ea61f100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] 网络不可达')': /packages/ed/60/15ee37d6d3385e6a432d39b5ac51f8467178ad989ba50f2b55681c1a038e/setuptools-59.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd0ea61f2b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] 网络不可达')': /packages/ed/60/15ee37d6d3385e6a432d39b5ac51f8467178ad989ba50f2b55681c1a038e/setuptools-59.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd0ea61f460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] 网络不可达')': /packages/ed/60/15ee37d6d3385e6a432d39b5ac51f8467178ad989ba50f2b55681c1a038e/setuptools-59.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd0ea61f640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] 网络不可达')': /packages/ed/60/15ee37d6d3385e6a432d39b5ac51f8467178ad989ba50f2b55681c1a038e/setuptools-59.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd0ea61f820>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] 网络不可达')': /packages/ed/60/15ee37d6d3385e6a432d39b5ac51f8467178ad989ba50f2b55681c1a038e/setuptools-59.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
  ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/ed/60/15ee37d6d3385e6a432d39b5ac51f8467178ad989ba50f2b55681c1a038e/setuptools-59.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd0ea61fa00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] 网络不可达'))
  
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding file:///home/jin/smac. Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-6ikzqo2m/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-awnh2not/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-6ikzqo2m/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-awnh2not/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `pip` seem to be unable to connect to pypi via https. Are you behind a firewall of some sort and need to configure a proxy?

Comment: China? Great Firewall? Forbidden HTTPS?